# Celery - minimize memory consumption

Tags: python, django, profiling, memory-management, celery

We have ~300 celeryd processes running under Ubuntu 10.4 64-bit , in idle every process takes ~19mb RES, ~174mb VIRT, thus - it's around 6GB of RAM in idle for all processes.
In active state - process takes up to 100mb of RES and ~300mb VIRT

Every process uses minidom(xml files are < 500kb, simple structure) and urllib.

Quetions is - how can we decrease RAM consuption - at least for idle workers, probably some celery or python options may help?
How to determine which part takes most of memory?

**UPD:** thats flight search agents, one worker for one agency/date. We have 10 agencies, one user search == 9 dates, thus we have 10*9 agents per one user search.

Is it possible start celeryd processes on demand to avoid idle workers(something like MaxSpareServers on apache)?

**UPD2:** Agent lifecycle is - send HTTP request, wait for response ~10-20 sec, parse xml( takes less then 0.02s), save result to MySQL

Comment: did you try serverfault.com or #celery on irc.freenode.net ?

Comment: serverfault is empty, unforunately

Comment: Why so many idle `celeryd` servers?

Comment: @S.Lott: +1, I have a big newsletter using only 8 workers, I can send 500k messages/hour. Hard to imagine an application that needs so many workers.

Comment: thats flight search agents, one worker for one agency/date. We have 10 agencies, one user search == 9 dates, thus we have 10*9 agents per one user search

Comment: @Andrew: (1) Please **update** your question, don't add comments.  (2) Why so many?  If they're idle more than 50% of the time, you have 2x as many as you need, right?  Why are there **any** idle servers?

Comment: @Andrew: if  you are connecting directly to flight company webservices I understand better the problem.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine - that's right, we have worker for each of 9 flight companies we work with

Answer (score 8):

Read this:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency

It sounds like you have one worker per celeryd.  That seems wrong.  You should have dozens of workers per celeryd.  Keep raising the number of workers (and lowering the number of celeryd's) until your system is very busy and very slow.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: "each worker spawns a new celeryd instance".  Doesn't seem right, when the documentation suggests "For example 3 celeryd’s with 10 worker processes each".

Comment: I'm running 'ps' on my server, at least with djcelery I see a main celeryd instance + one for each worker.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: I think the docs are only talking about the main instance.  But I'm not 100% sure.  At this point, you should probably be reading the celery docs more closely to see how it can be configured.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: I apologize for not being 100% sure.  Few things are 100% sure in my world.  Perhaps you have better experience in being totally right about something.  I don't know your configuration.  I don't know what you've done to setup celery or how you're using it.  I cannot really comment on what you're seeing at all, since I have zero facts on which to base my comments.  The lack of facts makes it very, very difficult to respond to your comment.  However, the link I provided does seem to provide useful information.  Perhaps you could read it?

Answer (score 3):

S. Lott is right.  The main instance consumes messages and delegates them to worker pool processes.  There is probably no point in running 300 pool processes on a single machine! Try 4 or 5 multiplied by the number of CPU cores.  You may gain something by running more than on celeryd with a few processes each, some people have, but you would have to experiment for your application.

See http://celeryq.org/docs/userguide/workers.html#concurrency

For the upcoming 2.2 release we're working on Eventlet pool support, this may
be a good alternative for IO-bound tasks, that will enable you to run 1000+ threads
with minimal memory overhead, but it's still experimental and bugs are being fixed
for the final release.

See http://groups.google.com/group/celery-users/browse_thread/thread/94fbeccd790e6c04

The upcoming 2.2 release also have support for autoscale, which adds/removes process on demand. See the Changelog:
http://ask.github.com/celery/changelog.html#version-2-2-0
 (this changelog is not completly written yet)

Comment: We run 300 workers as all of them do long http requests, thus they are busy until http response is received. Is there more correct way to resolve this problem?

Comment: As I said, the eventlet support in Celery master is much better at this sort of application. Chances are that you won't get any more requests/s with 300 processes than you do with 15 processes. (if you have 8 cores), more likely you will have less performance because it will be context switch trashing.

Answer (score 1):

The natural number of workers is close to the number of cores you have. The workers are there so that cpu-intensive tasks can use an entire core efficiently. The broker is there so that requests that don't have a worker on hand to process them are kept queued. The number of queues can be high, but that doesn't mean you need a high number of brokers either. A single broker should suffice, or you could shard queues to one broker per machine if it later turns out fast worker-queue interaction is beneficial.

Your problem seems unrelated to that. I'm guessing that your agencies don't provide a message queue api, and you have to keep around lots of requests. If so, you need a few (emphasis on not many) evented processes, for example twisted or node.js based.

Answer (score 1):

Use autoscaling. This allows the number of workers under each celeryd instance to be increased or descreased as needed. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoscaling