# celery worker max memory per child not working

Tags: python, celery

i am using celery for some tasks that no need to much memory (something like 2 MB is enough . more of task is loop with sleep 10 sec) but i have 100 or more tasks like this and this tasks giving so many times ( some times 10 days ) and data not stored in memory because it will saved in data base so no need many memory but every worker of celery giving so huge of server memory ( like 100 MB per worker )

so i search and see some [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346318/celery-minimize-memory-consumption)

it suggested to use `gevent` or `evenlet` but this pools not supporting killing(`revoke()`) task ( i need that )

and other solution was using auto-scale but it don`t make memory usage lower ( at 100 task no help )

so i decide to set max memory usage and test bellow code but not work

in celery_config.py

```
app = Celery('myproj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.conf.update(worker_max_memory_per_child=8000)  # 8MB
```

so i try other code as bellow and not work again

in settings.py

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'
# above codes working but bellow not
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
```

so i try other code

in supervisord.d/myproj_celery.conf

```
command=/var/www/myproj/venv/bin/celery worker -A myproj --loglevel=INFO --max-memory-per-child=2000 --autoscale=15,2 --concurrency=5
# autoscale work but memory usage of every worker still 100MB
```

any solution or any lead to new way??

i am using python3.8 and celery 4.4.0 and django==2.1.* and server centos 7